# Non proportional random sample

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas dataframe` such as this one :

```
deviceID    timestamp   time_since_previous_timestamp
A           3           NaN            
A           14          11            
A           127         113
A           133         6              
# 7k other data points for deviceID = A                                  
B           1           NaN 
B           12          11
# 1.5k other datapoints for deviceID = B                                  
C           42          NaN
C           48          6
# 600 other data points for deviceID = C
```

And so on, basically I have no control over how many datapoints I have for each `deviceID`, and it can vary a lot.

In order to plot something without my plot being skewed by the fact that some `deviceID` have many more datapoints than others, I thought about taking a random sample of my dataframe that would aim to get approximately the same number of datapoints from each `deviceID` (ie : my sample would have ~400 rows with `deviceID = A`, ~400 with `deviceID = B`, ~400 with `deviceID = C`, and so on)

How can I do that ? (Using `pandas` and/or `numpy` and/or neither).

---

**EDIT :** What I'm plotting :

First, I'm grouping on `time_since_previous_timestamp` and counting :

```
time_since_previous_timestamp         count
NaN                                   3
6                                     2
11                                    2
113                                   1
```

And then plotting `count` as y-axis and `time_since_previous_timestamp` as x-axis.

Comment: what will you plot?

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, but I've added the answer to your question in OP. Please note I modified the dataset too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with specifying `n=400` combined with [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then concatenate all the parts using [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df.loc[df.ID == 'A'].sample(n=400),df.loc[df.ID == 'B'].sample(n=400),df.loc[df.ID == 'C'].sample(n=400)])
```

example test:

```
#df:
#    B ID
#0  10  A
#1   9  A
#2   8  A
#3   7  A
#4   6  B
#5   5  B
#6   4  B
#7   3  C
#8   2  C
#9   1  C

df = pd.concat([df.loc[df.ID == 'A'].sample(n=2),df.loc[df.ID == 'B'].sample(n=2),df.loc[df.ID == 'C'].sample(n=2)])
```

output:

```
    B ID
0  10  A
3   7  A
6   4  B
5   5  B
8   2  C
7   3  C
```

you could also fix `random_state` to always have the same random sample.

I believe that's what you asked for.